# Estimates for a subset of observations : how to proceed

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation

Please note that I don't know the name of what I am trying to do, so maybe there is a lot of theory on it, or questions I couldn't find.

I am trying to estimate the value of a parameter in my model with respect to different categories.

For example, I have different number of trials and success for different categories :

Cat 1 :   100 trials,   2 successes

Cat 2 :   1000 trials,   30 successes

Cat 3 :   10 trials,   1 successes

My problem is that the number of trials can vary a lot, and the significance of the estimator as well.

So I used the following technique :

- Compute the global conversion rate (of aggregated categories, by summing the number of trials and success). It is the "Global estimator"
- For each category, compute the conversion rate of this category. It is "personal estimator"
- Call x the p-value of the hypothesis : "The conversion rate of the category is equal to the Global Estimator"
- (Caveat : This will make cringe mathematicians) My Estimator is then equal to

  ```
  Global Estimator x coeff + Personal Estimator x (1-coeff)
  ```

where coeff is an increasing function of the p-value, whose value is comprised between 0 and 1

The problem with this approach is for very small samples : in a world where the conversion rate is 3%, a sample with 1 success for 3 or 4 trials will reject the null hypothesis, but I would still want to keep the estimated conversion rate close to the generic rate, so I'm guessing I cannot be satisfied by my formula.

My question is the following:   Are there statistical tools (theoric or heuristic) that enable me to perform the estimation I want ?  If so, how is what I am trying to achieve (i.e. decide between "general estimator" and "global estimator") named ?

At the moment, my only way to go would be to tweak the model by hand, and it is already not very clean in a mathematical sense. So before I do this I wanted to check

To clarify :

The parameter I want to estimate is just the conversion rate (i.e. the p parameter of a Bernouilli/Binomial law).

I try to estimate this rate for several categories (in my case several products with different conversion rates and different number of trials).

The "model" I refer to is my heuristic to compute the estimator of each category, i.e.  for now :    Estimator of category i = Success(category i) /Trials(cat i) * (1-lambda) + (lambda) * Success (all categories)/Trials(all categories

A good example of what happens is when the category has a really small number of trials :

e.g. a category has 1 success for 3 trials while the general conversion rate is 3%

The hypothesis that the category conversion rate is 3% is going to have a small p-value, thus leading to the use of an estimator close to the 33% empirical estimator for this category  (While i'd rather stick to the generic category estimator)

The way I tweaked my "model" to counter that artifact is that I now only use this category estimator if the number of expected success under H0 is above an arbitrary threshold (in my case 1). It is not clean at all, but it takes care of the most blatant cases of my bias.

Comment: (1) How is "conversion rate" related to the abstract setup you initially describe?  (2) Exactly what is this "parameter" you are trying to estimate? Your discussion of disparate results for different categories strongly suggests you are modeling your data with multiple parameters. (3) What exactly do you mean by terms like "generic rate"?  (4) Since you refer at the end to a "model," why not just tell us precisely what that model is so we can understand what you need?

Comment: You could read up on logistic regression (for high-ish conversion rates in not so many trials) or count regression with an offset (for small conversion rates in lots of trials) with a dummy variable to represent the categories. These are standard tools, so using them will normally beat making something up.